# How to copy maven project to a no-internet-connection machine with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a project using maven+ springboot developed with Eclipse. Now I want to copy it to another server.
I just copied the source project folder and paste it on the other server, it's imported as maven project successfully but there is an issue: Lots of dependencies are missing and that server has no internet connection.
So is this the correct way to transfer maven project between two no-connection-machines? and how do I get all the dependency jars in pom.xml? Any help? Thx.

Comment: Do you use a version control tool? Is that within a corporate environment ? If so you should use a repository inside your organization...to handle such things

Comment: Do you want to _build_ the projekt on the new server or just _run_ it?

Comment: @ Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen. modify and build it.

Comment: Then you need to copy the whole contents of your `.m2` folder in your home directory as well.  This is where all your downloaded dependencies are stored.   You should strongly consider having a Maven proxy set up and be available to your offline build server because that will work better.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the project has been built successfully on a first server... You should copy missing dependencies from [Maven local repository](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-local-repository) of the first server to the second server. Mind the directory structure.